# Custom Module is being used by batch classes and cannot be removed

Tags: kofax

I would like to remove my custom module from the Kofax administration module but I can't because I get the following error

[image]

Using the module multiple times increases the amount of batch classes listed there. But there is only one batch class so this can't be.

I removed the module from the batch class queue, stopped all background services and have no forms app running. The only way to remove this module is to export the batch class, delete it in the administration module, delete the custom module and reimport the batch class.

Maybe I don't exit the application properly?

My session management:

```
    public void LoginToRuntimeSession()
    {
        login = new Login();
        login.EnableSecurityBoost = true;
        login.Login();
        login.ApplicationName = Resources.CUSTOM_MODULE_ID;
        login.Version = "1.0";
        login.ValidateUser($"{Resources.CUSTOM_MODULE_ID}.exe", false);

        session = login.RuntimeSession;
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        session.Dispose();
        login.Logout();
    }
```

I get a new active batch with this code

```
    public IBatch GetNextBatch()
    {
        return session.NextBatchGet(login.ProcessID);
    }
```

and this is how I process the batch after polling for new ones

```
    public void ProcessBatch(IBatch batch)
    {
        // ... IACDataElement stuff            

        batch.BatchClose(KfxDbState.KfxDbBatchReady, KfxDbQueue.KfxDbQueueNext, 0, "");
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix this "bug"? Please let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 0):

The message you are seeing is only referring to the configuration in the Administration module.  Therefore it is not related to what your module actually does when it is running or closing (no problem in your code can cause this).

If you are using Kofax Capture 11, previous published versions of the batch class remain in the system, so these probably still count as references to the module.  If you go to the Publish dialog window, you can click the "Versions..." button to see and delete older versions.  Try to remove your module again after you have deleted all the older versions that were still using it.

Additionally, you can look through the batch class properties to make sure that this module isn't set in one of the other settings, such as the module to start foldering on the Foldering tab, or the module to start Partial Batch Export on the Advanced tab.

If neither of those suggestions work, then you may want to open a case with Kofax Technical Support.  One thing that either they or you can do is open the admin.xml file in the exported batch class cab file and see where your module ID is found.  That will give context for finding out what is still referencing the module.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Well my batch class is not using versions so the button is disabled. Further I disabled all the settings you mentioned. I will open a case

Comment: Thanks.  If a webex doesn't get it solved, add the batch class to the case (whether they ask for it or not ) and ask them to determine where in the batch class (admin.xml) there is still a reference to your module.